# java sql insert

Tags: sql

I got a table with 4 fields:

> id, int(11), auto increament email, varchar(32) pass, varchar(32)
>   date_created, date

My question is how my query should look like?
I mean I don't need to insert the first value to id because it's auto increment but I have to insert all of the values..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQL you can specify which columns you want to set in the `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO table_name(email, pass, date_created) VALUES(?, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score 15):

First of all, I hope you're using PreparedStatements.

Assuming you have a Connection object named conn and two strings email and password...

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table_name(email, pass, date_created) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

stmt.setString(1, email);
stmt.setString(2, password);
stmt.setDate(3, new Date());

stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can insert in the format

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (Your Columns) VALUES (Your Values)
```

So for e.g.

```
INSERT INTO Test_Table (email, pass, data_created) VALUES ('john@blah.com', 'pass', to_date(string, format))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using parameters-`tsql`; ***(better to pass values in parameters rather than as strings)***

```
Insert into [YourTableName] (email, pass, date_created) 
values (@email, @pass, @date_created)
```