# How should I insert data from a program in java to a database in mysql?

Tags: java, mysql

this is the code what I am using to insert the data. **Is this the best way?**

```
       try 
      {
           st =  conect.createStatement();
           sql_v = "insert into VENDEDORES(ID,name,firstlast_name,secondlast_name,phone,celphone) \n"
                  + " values("+ID+",'name','fln','sln','ph','clp')";

          st.executeUpdate(sql_v);
      } 
      catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"","ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
      }
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving  working code. It is more suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [java sql insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980144/java-sql-insert)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this the best way?

No its not the best way.

I suggest to use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Advantage of using `PreparedStatement` over `Statement`

- A SQL statement is `precompiled` and stored in a PreparedStatement object.
- This object can then be used to `efficiently` execute this statement multiple times.
- Reduces execution time.
- Automatic prevention of [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) by builtin escaping of quotes and other special characters

Read more [PreparedStatements and performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271249/difference-between-statement-and-preparedstatement)

Here is the [sample code](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/) provided by mkyong

Comment: protection against SQL injection should really be #1

Comment: @Cruncher that's I used bullet points instead of giving it numbering.

Comment: I get it. I was just emphasising. BTW, I'm pretty sure that if you one-off a prepared statement, then it's actually slower than a statement. I could be wrong on that though.